# Insertion of current carrying metal sheet between the plates of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: experimental-physics, capacitance, electronics

[image]
A parallel plate capacitor with area of plates A and distance between them d is charged with Voltage V1. A metal sheet carrying current is inserted between the sheets. How does the system change? What's going on in between the plates? 
I have indicated the dielectric in yellow. The surrounding is air.

Note: The plate inserted has a lateral surface area larger than the plates of the parallel plate capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

In general, inserting a metal sheet between the plates of a capacitor turns it into two larger capacitors connected in series. If the sheet is thin, the resulting equivalent capacitance will be roughly the same. If the sheet is thick, the resulting equivalent capacitance will be greater than the original.

Passing a DC current through the sheet would not affect voltages or currents in the original circuit. This is electrically equivalent to two independent circuits sharing one node (metal sheet in this case). For DC, such circuits should not interfere with each other.